# Can a Django view return its header first?

Tags: python, django, wsgi

I have a particularly heavy view which may need to return a form posting to itself several times, but I need the header straight away.

Is there any way for the header portion of the template to be returned first? e.g. my view returns something like:

```
return HttpResponse(Template('
  {% extends "base.html" %}
  {% block content %} FOO {% endblock %}
'))
```

Ideally I want to be able to do something like:

```
partialResponse = request.renderUntilBlock('content')
# lots of work
return partialResponse.extend(Template('
  {% block content %} FOO {% endblock %}
'))
```

Update: Obviously PHP is structured differently but this is what I'm hoping to emulate:

```
<?php
echo '<html><head><title>Hi!</title</head><body>';
ob_flush(); flush();
# header has now been output to the client
# do lots of work
echo '<h1>done</h1></body></html>';
?>
```

Comment: Let me make sure I understand, because I don't think I do :)  Do you want to render up to the content block, return to the view and return an `HttpResponse` containing the page up until that point, then have the view resume rendering the rest of the page?  You of course can't do that directly.

Comment: @dappawit Just updated the question, hope that clarifies it :)

Comment: Alright... so is it that you want to be able to render the page in increments?  Render up to the content block, then go back to the view, then render some more, go back to the view, etc.

Comment: @dappawit I only need to render the page once, but there will be a large time gap between the header and the rest of the content so I want to make sure the header is rendered first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't fully test this, but this should work according to the docs.

```
from django.template import Context, Template

def responder():
    yield '' # to make sure the header is sent

    # do all your work

    t = Template('''
        {% extends "base.html" %}
        {% block content %} FOO {% endblock %}
    ''')
    yield t.render(Context({}))

return HttpResponse(responder())
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  What you need to do is capture each individual render as a string, then concatenate the strings to form the complete content of the response.

Here is the low-level way:

```
from django.template import Context, Template
t1 = Template("My name is {{ my_name }}.")
c1 = Context({"my_name": "Adrian"})
s = t.render(c1)
t2 = Template("My name is {{ my_name }}.")
c2 = Context({"my_name": "Adrian"})  # You could also use the same context with each template if you wanted.
s += t.render(c2)

return HttpResponse(s)
```

However, if you want to do this for performance reasons, I would make sure to compare the time it takes to render all at once versus rendering in pieces.  I think rendering all at once is the best way to go in general.  You can't return the Response until the entire thing is rendered anyway.

Comment: This does seem on the right track, but doesn't it still deliver the whole page in one go? The crux of my question is being able to render the header *to the client* first, before the delay of the work in my view.

Comment: oh, then there is no way to do that using only Django, you have to go the AJAX route.  Rendering in Django is rendering on the server, it has nothing to do with rendering in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to do this directly. Your best bet is to simply return a page with just the header and a javascript function that fetches the rest of the page's data via AJAX.

Comment: The reason I'm unwilling to do this via ajax is that this view may have to return a form several times, so I'd have to do all that form handling via ajax too.

Comment: Then maybe you have to rethink the design?

Comment: @Drew, @dappawit, I've updated the question again with a PHP example.

Comment: @Long Ears: Before going to all this trouble, I'd measure performance and see that this functionality is really warranted and would benefit your application.

Comment: @dappawit In this case the view may take 10 seconds then return a form to be submitted to itself which will take another 10 seconds when submitted. I need the header output first to set up a JS listener for the message queue reporting on all this.

Comment: @Long Ears: 10 seconds? Wow. It sounds like there's got to be a better way (although obviously I don't know your requirements so maybe there isn't).  Unfortunately, I don't know of a way to do what you want to do directly in Django.  There may be some technique that I'm unaware of.  (Which is highly likely--of all the techniques there are, I know but a small fraction.)

Comment: @Drew, @dappawit thanks very much. I'll leave the question open for a while longer in case someone has a sudden brainwave but your help is very much appreciated :)